# Is there a naming convention for HTML form fields for good auto completion across all modern browsers?

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete, naming-conventions, autofill

Is there a naming convention for form fields? For what fields do Chrome, IE, Firefox look for? I mean, one for all, or at least most of the modern browsers.

I stumbled upon:

- http://wonderfullyflawed.com/2009/02/17/rails-forms-microformat
- http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/using-ecml-11-to-make-website-forms-compatible-with-google-toobar-autofill-and-wand/ -> talking about http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3106.txt
- [Names of HTML form naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142591/names-of-html-form-naming-conventions)
- [Form field names used by personal data auto-fill in browsers (Safari, Opera)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027462/form-field-names-used-by-personal-data-auto-fill-in-browsers-safari-opera)

e.g. the ECML approach uses such names:

```
Description               Field name
----------------------------------------------------------
ship to title             Ecom_ShipTo_Postal_Name_Prefix
ship to first name        Ecom_ShipTo_Postal_Name_First
ship to middle name       Ecom_ShipTo_Postal_Name_Middle
ship to last name         Ecom_ShipTo_Postal_Name_Last

user ID                   Ecom_User_ID
user password             Ecom_User_Password
```

But those "Ecom_..." form fields appear odd to me?

I know about the IE-only and proprietary (of course) attribute `VCARD_NAME="vCard.xyz"`, but it's an invalid html attribute.

Or is the best shot, to write the fields in the most common way like @F. B. suggests at [Form field names used by personal data auto-fill in browsers (Safari, Opera)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027462/form-field-names-used-by-personal-data-auto-fill-in-browsers-safari-opera/1348601#1348601)

---

Small Update (2015-07-21) - just stumbled upon this [Google Developer Blog](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill) post which mentions the **WHATWG HTML** specs for Autofill:

> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#autofill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have linked to the answers. If you are not using high-level frameworks like CakePHP or Ruby on Rails, though, the first and third links do not apply.

The thing is, it's Google Toolbar and Wand's **job** to fill out forms successfully. Given the scope of the internet, the toolbar must have *tons* of redundancy.

Therefore, as long as you keep your form fields **semanticly named**, the form should autofill.

ECML is E-Commerce Modeling Language. `Ecom_` simply stands for E-Commerce. If you need to sell stuff, use that naming convention.

Comment: I agree, for example I tend to use username for a username and email for an email field. firstname, fname and first_name all pre-fill as the browsers understand all of these. Make sure you use some spam control like a hidden field with a dynamic value that can be recreated by the server and checked to stop robots

Comment: Hmmm. But since field naming from the coding perspective is basically arbitrary - they could be called anything and still work - it seems an ideal area to have a "best practice" or microformat. Sure you *can* use any vaguely semantic name for an "email" field for auto completion to work, but the *standard* one is **xxxx**. That would really help.

Comment: Good point. Perhaps there is a convention I am not yet aware of. It does seem as though there isn't, though, as I have not come across a single reference to such spec. It might make sense to ask a W3C working group or something.