# HTML Form name/address fields and autofill

Tags: html, forms

Is there a best practice naming convention for name and address HTML form fields so that browser autofills work as well as they can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this SO answer [Is there a naming convention for HTML form fields for good auto completion across all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365395/is-there-a-naming-convention-for-html-form-fields-for-good-auto-completion-across)

It has many links to other SQ questions/answers and other websites with more info.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at those.